# Upgrading to Gimp 2.8 PPA fails with "dpkg-deb error"?

Tags: upgrade, ppa, gimp

*Upgrading Gimp gives the following error:*

```
Preparing to replace gimp 2.6.12-1ubuntu1 (using .../gimp_2.8.0-1ubuntu0ppa3~precise_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gimp ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.8.0-1ubuntu0ppa3~precise_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-xmc', which is also in package gimp-plugin-registry 3.5.4-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.8.0-1ubuntu0ppa3~precise_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't correctly remove gimp-plugin-registry and it's still giving conflicts as seen in error messages. Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --purge gimp gimp-plugin-registry
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: thank you m_gol.
I tied and successed,but also need remove gimp-gmic.
detail infos: http://dpaste.com/743555/

Comment: @kafeitu I can't tell, did this solve the problem for you as it did for me (Hooray)? If so you should accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you, for you have helped me resolve my ubuntu box from boot failure after installing GIMP 2.8. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 5):

You should have removed the GIMP Plugin Registry package before upgrading :

`sudo apt-get remove gimp-plugin-registry`

because the package hasn't been compiled with  GIMP 2.8 support.

**Now , run the following:**

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/gimp-28-stable-finally-available-for.html)

Comment: I tried it,but still error, detail infos to visit: http://dpaste.com/743166/

Comment: @kafeitu  try `sudo apt-get -f install` , and if still there is an error you'll need to purge the ppa and start over the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reinstall GIMP.  After you uninstalled it type`apt-get install gimp` in the terminal to install it.

Comment: I tried too, error infos:
http://dpaste.com/743167/

Answer (score 1):

1. Before updating GIMP from `2.6` to `2.8`, you will have to install **Ubuntu** Tweak from the terminal with:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa`

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

   *Note*: Ignore if you have it.
2. Open Ubuntu Tweak --> Admin tab --> Source center --> Image.
3. Check Gimp 2.8 RC and click Refresh button at the bottom.
4. Now open Update Manager from launcher and find updates for Gimp 2.8.
5. Install updates and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

first try to upgrade it.Otherwise try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gimp
```